# Importing path to settings Django (django-rest-auth)

Tags: python, django, path, django-rest-auth

I am stuck with very trivial thing in Django, and that is I don't know how to define path to REGISTER_SERIALIZER in main settings file. I am using http://django-rest-auth.readthedocs.io/en/latest/configuration.html. I added all the apps, and it works without custom serializer. I just need to know how to add valid path this (you can check link for library example).

This is what I tried:

```
REST_AUTH_REGISTER_SERIALIZERS = {
    'REGISTER_SERIALIZER' : os.path.join(BASE_DIR, "rest\\rest_user_profile\\serializers.RegisterSerializer")
}
```

the path is correct and still I get

```
ImportError: No module named 'C:\\...\\rest\\rest_user_profile\\serializers'
```

Comment: Why are you using back slashes? I think that's what's throwing it off.

Comment: I found a solution, I should not have been using absolute path but insted app name and path to module. This is what I did `REST_AUTH_REGISTER_SERIALIZERS = {
    'REGISTER_SERIALIZER' : 'rest.rest_user_profile.serializers.RegisterSerializer'
}`